# Fine particle adhesion to larger particles

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

Does static electricity cause smaller particles(dust size) to stick to larger particles?  For example when doing gradations on fine aggregate samples from 1/2" size down to passing a 200 sieve size we routinely have the 100 size and down sticking to larger size particles.  Would humidity have an effect on this and if so could I increase or decrease the humidity to help the separation of particle sizes to be sieved?  Would the electric heat system in a building contribute to this issue?   Would sieving the material at a hotter or cooler temperature help?  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Agglomeration of fines during sieving operations is common, and static electricity is the cause. Its effects can be minimized by increasing the humidity, but if the fines are water-soluble or hydrophilic the problem can be made worse because of clumping in this case.

There are static electricity-generating devices which are used to cancel the charge buildup on the sieved particles, but I do not know where they are sold.